# Css for Glade/GTK

Tags: css, gtk

I wanted to ask if it is possible to know what are the properties of the GTK Theme parser..

I have a glade file and a css file.

In the glade file i have some objects which have a class descripted in the css file.

I wanted to make the cursor invisible at some condition but if i write on the css file

cursor: none;

then when I start the application, a theme parsing error comes up saying that cursor is not a valid property name..

Can i see then all the property of this theme? Can I modify it?

I red documentations on the gtk site but didn't find the answer for this question

Thank you

Found on a site this:
GTK+ currently supports a subset of CSS properties:

```
        background-color
        background-image
        color
        border-color
        border-image
        border-radius
        border-width
        border-style
        padding
        margin
        transition
```

Is there a way to modify this list to add something like cursor property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a list of all the CSS properties that GTK supports, from the GTK documentation: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-properties.html
There are more than the ones you listed, but unfortunately, `cursor` is still not among those.

To get support for `cursor`, you can't simply "modify that list" — you would have to implement support for the `cursor` property in GTK. However, you can easily work around the lack of this property in code, by connecting to the `enter-notify-event` and `leave-notify-event` signals on the widget that you want to change the cursor on, and using `gdk_window_set_cursor()` to set the cursor that you want.

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/css-properties.html